# If we have a vector x this vector is element of Null(Matrix)?

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a vector x  with these values

$X=\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 
-14 \\ 
4 
\end{bmatrix}$

and a matrix A with these values

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -8 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 7\\ 
0 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$

We can say that the vector X E Null(A) I have this, if we make a multiply between the matrix A and the vector X we need to the result be zero by a theorem, in this case, the final matrix I have that is

$=\begin{bmatrix}
126\\ 
28 \\ 
-8
\end{bmatrix}$

so it is different from zero, my question is, we can say that the vector x is not an element of Nul(A)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The nullspace of a matrix $A$ the linear subspace of the domain of $A$ that is mapped to the zero vector. Since $AX$ does not equal 0, $X \notin$ null($A$).

Comment: Thank you so much